# Rails' Devise Edit Profile Page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to place the form field into a partial '_form.html.slim' but when I do that and I render the partial in my 'edit.html.slim', the form is not being fully rendered. From my browser's inspector, it says that only the form element (not including the input tags and submit button) is being rendered in the modified 'edit.html.slim'.

Here is the original 'edit.html.slim'

```
.row
  .small-8.columns.small-centered
    .form-panel
      p.welcome 
        | Edit 
        = resource_name.to_s.humanize

      = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, \ 
        url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {method: :put}) do |f|
        = devise_error_messages!

        .row
          .small-3.columns = f.label :username, class: 'right'
          .small-9.columns = f.text_field :username, autofocus: true

        .row
          .small-3.columns = f.label :email, class: 'right'
          .small-9.columns = f.text_field :email

        .row
          .small-3.columns = f.label :name, class: 'right'
          .small-9.columns = f.text_field :name

        .row
          .small-8.columns.small-centered
            = f.submit 'Save changes', class: 'button small expand'

      = link_to 'Back', :back
```

Here is the modified 'edit.html.slim' that renders the form partial

```
.row
  .small-8.columns.small-centered
    .form-panel
      p.welcome 
        | Edit 
        = resource_name.to_s.humanize

      #profile_form
        = render 'form'
```

And here is the '_form.html.slim' partial

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {method: :put}) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

    .row
      .small-3.columns = f.label :username, class: 'right'
      .small-9.columns = f.text_field :username, autofocus: true

    .row
      .small-3.columns = f.label :email, class: 'right'
      .small-9.columns = f.text_field :email

    .row
      .small-3.columns = f.label :name, class: 'right'
      .small-9.columns = f.text_field :name

    .row
      .small-8.columns.small-centered
        = f.submit 'Save changes', class: 'button small expand'
```

Update:
The error in my code was the indentation of the divs under "= devise_error_message!". Since slim relies heavily on indentation, the divs were seen to be part of the "= devise_error_message!" which should not be the case. Here's the working code:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {method: :put}) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

  .row
    .small-3.columns = f.label :username, class: 'right'
    .small-9.columns = f.text_field :username, autofocus: true

  .row
    .small-3.columns = f.label :email, class: 'right'
    .small-9.columns = f.text_field :email

  .row
    .small-3.columns = f.label :name, class: 'right'
    .small-9.columns = f.text_field :name

  .row
    .small-8.columns.small-centered
      = f.submit 'Save changes', class: 'button small expand'
```

Comment: Did this solution work?

Comment: No it didn't work. But I found what the error is - it's on the indentation of form fields. Slim wrapped the divs that contain the form fields under "= devise_error_messages!" because of the indentation.